# Update wizard says always_populate_raw_post_data is on 0, but it is already on -1

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade

I try to update my Magento 2.0.2, but the servercheck says wrong always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. But it is already correct on -1. I can confirm it in phpinfo. And there is no other ini file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i solved by change always_populate_ras_post_data=-1 in `php.ini CLI (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini)`